# How to run CoffeeScript files, or spec.coffee from the terminal?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to solve the first problem in Exercism using CoffeeScript, and I want to run the file `spec.coffee`. How should I run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that the coffee file has to be compiled as js file first.
I used `coffee -c file.spec.coffee` to compile first to js 
from *file.spec.coffee* into *file.spec.js*
then run `jasmine-node file.spec.js`

**-- UPDATE --**

I should have checked the Help section which provides instruction on how to run exercises for languages used in exercism like
http://help.exercism.io/getting-started-with-coffeescript.html